# Ruby error : undefined method `any ' for 30:Fixnum (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, spree

I am trying to list the product reviews in spree back end. But getting the error 'undefined method any '. I am new to ruby,please help me to solve this issue.

Thanks in Advance.

***Index.html.erb:***

```
<% if @reviews.any? %>
<table class="index">
    <colgroup>
        <col style="width: 25%;">
        <col style="width: 10%;">
        <col style="width: 10%;">
        <col style="width: 20%;">
        <col style="width: 15%;">
        <col style="width: 17%;">
    </colgroup>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><%= Spree.t('product') %></th>
            <th><%= Spree::Review.human_attribute_name(:rating) %></th>
            <th><%= Spree.t('feedback') %></th>
            <th><%= Spree::Review.human_attribute_name(:user) %></th>
            <th><%= Spree::Review.human_attribute_name(:created_at) %></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <%- @reviews.each do |review| -%>
        <tr id="<%= dom_id review %>">
            <td>
                <% if review.product %>
                    <%= link_to review.product.name, product_path(review.product) %>
                <% end %>
            </td>
            <td class="align-center">
                <%= txt_stars(review.rating) %>
            </td>
            <td class="align-center">
                <%= link_to "(#{review.feedback_stars}/#{review.feedback_reviews.size})", admin_review_feedback_reviews_path(review) %>
            </td>
            <td class="align-center">
                <%= review.user_id ? link_to(review.user.try(:email), [:admin, review.user]) : Spree.t(:anonymous) %></p>
                <p><%= Spree::Review.human_attribute_name(:ip_address) %>: <%= review.ip_address ? link_to(review.ip_address, "http://whois.domaintools.com/#{review.ip_address}") : '-' %></p>
            </td>
            <td class="align-center">
                <%= l review.created_at, :format => :short %>
            </td>
            <td class="actions">
                <%= link_to_with_icon 'check', Spree.t('approve'), approve_admin_review_url(review), :no_text => true, class: 'approve' unless review.approved %>
                &nbsp;
                <%= link_to_edit review, :no_text => true, :class => 'edit' %>
                &nbsp;
                <%= link_to_delete review, :no_text => true %>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <% end %>
    </tbody>
</table>
<% else %>
<div class="no-objects-found">
    <%= Spree.t(:no_results) %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

The above shown is the index.html.erb file , where the listing and ransack search is done.

Model File : ***review.rb***

```
class Spree::Review < ActiveRecord::Base

      belongs_to :product, touch: true
      belongs_to :user, :class_name => Spree.user_class.to_s
      has_many   :feedback_reviews

      after_save :recalculate_product_rating, :if => :approved?
      after_destroy :recalculate_product_rating

      validates :name, presence: true
      validates :review, presence: true

      validates :rating, numericality: { only_integer: true,
      greater_than_or_equal_to: 1, 
      less_than_or_equal_to: 5,
      message: Spree.t('you_must_enter_value_for_rating') }


      default_scope { order("spree_reviews.created_at DESC") }

      scope :localized, ->(lc) { where('spree_reviews.locale = ?', lc) }
      scope :most_recent_first, -> { order('spree_reviews.created_at DESC') }
      scope :oldest_first, -> { reorder('spree_reviews.created_at ASC') }
      scope :preview, -> { limit(Spree::Reviews::Config[:preview_size]).oldest_first }
      scope :approved, -> { where(approved: true) }
      scope :not_approved, -> { where(approved: false) }
      scope :default_approval_filter, -> { Spree::Reviews::Config[:include_unapproved_reviews] ? all : approved }

      def feedback_stars
      return 0 if feedback_reviews.size <= 0
      ((feedback_reviews.sum(:rating) / feedback_reviews.size) + 0.5).floor
      end

      def set_search
      @search=Product.search(params[:q])
      end

      def recalculate_product_rating
      self.product.recalculate_rating if product.present?
      end
      end
```

***reviews_controller.rb***

```
          class Spree::Admin::ReviewsController < Spree::Admin::ResourceController
      helper Spree::ReviewsHelper

      def index
      @reviews = collection
      end

      def approve
      r = Spree::Review.find(params[:id])

      if r.update_attribute(:approved, true)
      flash[:notice] = Spree.t("info_approve_review")
      else
      flash[:error] = Spree.t("error_approve_review")
      end
      redirect_to admin_reviews_path
      end

      def edit
      if @review.product.nil?
      flash[:error] = Spree.t("error_no_product")
      redirect_to admin_reviews_path and return
      end
      end

      private

      def collection
      params[:q] ||= {}
      @search = Spree::Review.ransack(params[:q])
      @collection = @search.result.includes([:product, :user, :feedback_reviews]).page(params[:page]).per(params[:per_page])
      end
      end
```

Comment: Show us the controller/view, specifically the line where you assign `@reviews`. It turned out you assigned an integer value to it. _Sidenote:_ “I am new to anything” should not be treated as _an excuse_.

Comment: You are getting wrong value in @reviews. It should be an array instead of fix num

Comment: The question has been updated (controller files have been added ). Please review it

Comment: `<% if @reviews.present? %>` use this instead of `<% if @reviews.any? %>`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the important code is in your comment on an answer, where it is very difficult to read.

I think you have assigned the variable `collection` with an integer id, and assigned the result if the database lookup to `@collection` (which is a different variable)

So to fix it you could change the index action to

```
@reviews = @collection
```

Comment: tried changing to `@reviews = @collection`. But no changes.     I have modified my controller and model.Please have a loot at it.there i have clearly written the code for def collection .

Answer (score -1):

`any` works with array on and your @reviews are not an array. Please check @reviews object. It should be array.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @Sachin R , when i checked @reviews , ` <%= @reviews.inspect %>` the value i got is an integer as ~ 30. am not getting an array of values.                                           its defined in controller as `def collection
      params[:q] ||= {}
      @search = Spree::Review.ransack(params[:q])
      @collection = @search.result.includes([:product, :user, :feedback_reviews]).page(params[:page]).per(params[:per_page])
      end`

Comment: can you change the name of method from collection to some other name?
 Maybe it will be conflicting some ruby method.

Comment: @Sachin R, Tried it. But no change